# C++ Gauss–Seidel method

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, equation

this is a piece of code for a simple iteration method for solving systems of linear algebraic equations:

```
double* iter(double** a, double* y, int n, int& iter)
{
    double* res = new double[n];
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        res[i] = y[i] / a[i][i];
    }

    double eps = 0.0001;
    double* Xn = new double[n];

    do {
        iter++;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Xn[i] = y[i] / a[i][i];
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                else {
                    Xn[i] -= a[i][j] / a[i][i] * res[j];
                }
            }
        }

        bool flag = true;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (fabs(Xn[i] - res[i]) > eps) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            res[i] = Xn[i];
        }

        if (flag)
            break;
    } while (1);

    return res;
}
```

and formula for it:
[image]

but I would like to implement the seidel method.and slightly changed the code according to the formula below

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Xn[i] = y[i] / a[i][i];
            for (j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                    Xn[i] -= a[i][j] / a[i][i] * Xn[j];
            }
            for (j = i+1; j < n; j++){
                Xn[i] -= a[i][j] / a[i][i] * res[j];
            }
        }
```

[image]

but I'm not getting exactly what I expected:

[image]

I would be grateful if you could tell me where I made a mistake. thank you in advance for your answers.

[image]

Comment: *I would be grateful if you could tell me where I made a mistake* -- Do a hand calculation, then [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and see where your program diverges from the hand calculation.

Comment: BTW, you would be far better off using `std::vector<double>` instead of `new double[]` and `double *`.  The code you have now leaks memory.

Comment: in the implement of second formula: for(j = i+1; j < n; ++j) should change to for(j = i; j < n; ++j). since in your formula, j is in range [i+1, n], but in your code j is in range [i+1, n). :)

Comment: @che.wang  if I do as you said, it will turn out what is in the screenshot (I attached to the question)

Comment: @Vs_De_S an example input. so we can check it ourself.

Comment: @che.wang I kind of managed to solve the problem, but I didn't figure out how myself. I haven't changed anything at all...but there was some other problem, haha..

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies in the new implementation.

The first sum of the Seidel method sums up to the element before the diagonal, while your for loop goes up to two elements before the diagonal.

Instead of
`for(j = 0; j < i-1; j++)`
you should have
`for(j = 0; j < i; j++)`

Note that Gauss Seidel method is applicable if the elements on the diagonal are non-zero.

Comment: I can't do it this way, then I will get the result as in the last screenshot in my question.